# bashtop and bpytop do not display properly in putty

Tags: linux, centos, process, top, ncurses

I have installed bashtop or bpytop (on a minimal CentOS install) but I just get a jumbled mess of colour blocks on the screen. I've made sure to do `sudo yum upgrade` and rebooted, but still garbled output. htop / mc work fine (I guess they use ncurses?). Can someone advise on what I could maybe look at to get bashtop / bpytop working? Maybe I'm missing some essential packages, or a Putty setting is required to get apps like these to render properly?

Comment: Hi, I see you're using Putty? This is caused by older versions of Putty not supporting True Colours however this was patched a few versions back. Update to the new version of Putty and you shouldn't have any problems - I myself had the same problem and was able to resolve it by updating.

Comment: I think you might have been right Michael. Ultimately, the problem went away and I had no idea why. I think it must have been an older version of putty.exe that I was using by accident. Thanks. 

Comment: Fantastic. From my research, this is because Bashtop and BPytop require True Colors.
https://github.com/aristocratos/bpytop/issues/196
Putty introduced this in version 0.71
https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/true-colour.html
I myself was using a version in the 0.6x area and just recently upgraded to 0.74 and found the issue resolved. I hope you find this interesting.